# Determining if user is adult in Django

Tags: django, python-datetime, django-custom-user

I'm attempting to determine if a user on my site is an adult by using his birthday and today's date.

I have a boolean attribute in my user called `adult` and I attempt to set it in the following way

```
from datetime import date

...

def set_adult(self):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - self.date_of_birth.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.date_of_birth.month, self.date_of_birth.day))
    if age > 18:
      self.adult = True
    else:
      self.adult = False
```

When registering a user, I have a field for adding a birthday

```
class MyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new account.
    """
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput,label="Email")
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'), label="Date of birth (MM/DD/YYYY)")
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password (again)")

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['email', 'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean(self):
        """
        Verifies that the values entered into the password fields match

        NOTE: Errors here will appear in ``non_field_errors()`` because it applies to more than one field.
        """
        cleaned_data = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).clean()
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match. Please enter both fields again.")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.set_adult # NOT WORKING
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

When I check my admin page after adding an "adult birthday", the result is always false.

Am I making a mistake in my form or in my `set_adult` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    user.set_adult # NOT WORKING
```

You are missing `()` in function call:

```
    user.set_adult()
```

Comment: Wow. That's silly, but it works now. Thank you so much. Sometimes Python's flexible syntax is a pain.